# Grails Upgrade to 3.3.x : Cannot access persistentEntity.relationshipMap and persistentEntity.hasOneMap with grails 3.3.5

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-3.3

As per the upgrade docs of grails 3.3.x (http://docs.grails.org/3.3.x/guide/upgrading.html)

GrailsDomainClass is deprecated with class PersistentEntity.java.

Now, I was trying to upgrade my grails application which was on 3.2.11 to 3.3.5

Here I removed all occurrences of GrailsDomainClass with PersistentEntity.
Now when I try to call :

Example:

```
PersistentEntity persistentEntity = grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")[0] as PersistentEntity;

println persistentEntity.relationshipMap
println persistentEntity.hasOneMap
```

> It gives me groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
>   relationshipMap for class: DefaultGrailsDomainClass1_groovyProxy
>
> And,
>
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hasOneMap for
>   class: DefaultGrailsDomainClass1_groovyProxy

Can someone help me with the correct api to get relationshipMap and hasOneMap.
I tried to search a lot regarding this but no success till now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

There is no direct api for this, But it can be accessed using:

```
Map hasOneMap = GrailsClassUtils.getStaticPropertyValue(persistentEntity.clazz, "hasOne") as Map
Map relationshipMap = GrailsClassUtils.getStaticPropertyValue(persistentEntity.clazz, "hasMany") as Map
```